# Flex api V2 (flex/v2/sessions) is giving VALIDATION_ERROR

Tags: cybersource

I am trying to create capturecontext using https://apitest.cybersource.com/flex/v2/sessions with below request payload

> {   "fields" : {
> "paymentInformation" : {
> "card" : {
> "number":"4111111111111111",
> "expirationMonth":"12",
> "expirationYear":"2031",
> "type":"001",
> "securityCode":"737"
> }
> }   } }

and getting below response

> "{"correlationId":"303ff124-e250-42fc-97ef-388369e3e2af","details":[{"location":"fields.paymentInformation.card","message":"Unknown
> field definition property"}],"message":"One or more validation
> errors occurred","reason":"VALIDATION_ERROR"}"
>
> Blockquote

I am following exactly same pattern mentioned on Cybersource developer guide.Can somebody please help me to identify the issue here.

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out? I'm currently working on a project using the Flex V2 API and the documentation is less than helpful

Answer (score 0):

The error says what's wrong:

"location":"fields.paymentInformation.card"

"message":"Unknown field definition property"

If you check in https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/digital-accept-flex/developer/all/rest/digital-accept-flex/flex-api-2/flex-api-2-generate-capture-context.html, the request should be something like:

```
{
  "fields" : {
    "paymentInformation" : {
      "card" : {
        "number" : { },
        "securityCode" : {
          "required" : false
        },
        "expirationMonth" : {
          "required" : false
        },
        "expirationYear" : {
          "required" : false
        },
        "type" : {
          "required" : false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.